# AtomicReferences for Intents and Activity Navigation in Helper File

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-context, atomicreference

In my app, I navigate between about 5 different screens, each in its own `activity`. Pretty much any `activity` can be called from any other `activity`, so I am trying to build a helper file to manage the `intents` so that I don’t have redundant code.

I built a helper file with `public static` methods and pass the activity `context` and any required data when calling these methods. This appears to be working fine on my device (Samsung Galaxy S5), but Android Studio recommends making my intents AtomicReference in my helper file.

Can you help me understand if and why these should be `AtomicReference<Intent>`?

Also, is it appropriate to pass `context` to a helper file to make these calls?

ActivityHelper file:

```
public class ActivityHelper {
private ActivityHelper() {}

public static void startAddNewMealActivity(Context context) {
    Intent newMealIntent = new Intent(context, MealEditActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(newMealIntent);
}

public static void startMealListActivity(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MealListActivity.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public static void startEditMealActivity(Context context, FBMeal meal, String mealFBKey) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MealEditActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_FB_KEY_EXTRA_TAG, mealFBKey);
    intent.putExtra(Constants.INTENT_MEAL_EXTRA_TAG, meal);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}

public static void startEditLastMealActivity(final Context context) {

    FBHelper.getQueryForMostRecentMeal().addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (FBHelper.isExistingDataSnapshop(dataSnapshot)) {

                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    FBMeal selectedMeal = snapshot.getValue(FBMeal.class);
                    String selectedMealId = snapshot.getKey();
                    startEditMealActivity(context, selectedMeal, selectedMealId);
                }
            } else {
                Utils.showToastFromStringResource(R.string.no_meals, context);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Utils.showToastFromStringResource(R.string.error_getting_meal, context);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Example of calling helper file from menu in AppCompatActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit_meal_menu:
            ActivityHelper.startEditMealActivity(this, meal, mealFBKey);
            return true;
        case R.id.edit_last_entry_menu:
            ActivityHelper.startEditLastMealActivity(this);
            return true;
        case R.id.about_menu:
            DialogFragment newFragment = AboutDialog.newInstance();
            newFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "about");
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Another approach would be to create a `BaseActivity` class that extends `AppCompatActivity` and includes all of your helper methods. All of your activities should then extend `BaseActivity`. In that case, you would not need to pass a `Context` to all of these helper methods, since the helper methods would be non-static and can just use `this` as `Context`.

Comment: And I cannot see any reason at all why you would need to use an `AtomicReference` in any of your `static` methods.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidWasser. I rebuilt my helper file as a `BaseActivity` as you suggested. This is much cleaner and easier to manage. I'm still not sure why Android Studio suggested `AtomicReference`, but it worked fine either way.

Comment: Glad to hear that. I posted my comments as an answer. Maybe it will help someone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see any reason at all why you would need to use an `AtomicReference` in any of your `static` methods.

Another approach would be to create a `BaseActivity` class that extends `AppCompatActivity` and includes all of your helper methods. All of your activities should then extend `BaseActivity`. In that case, you would not need to pass a `Context` to all of these helper methods, since the helper methods would be non-static and can just use `this` as `Context`.